# amount of diagnosis for <5 >5 and amount of male and female mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one is holding customer info and another diagnosis done to the customers. I want to get amount of diagnosis done for <5  >5 and amount of  male/female who got the diagnosis.

TABLES:

```
customers
**NAME**       **PID**      **BIRTH_DATE**    **SEX**
chris             1            1980-07-01        m
Jane              2            1977-10-05        f
Anna              3            1990-5-10         f
David             4            2008-1-10         m
Naomi             5            2009-10-20        f
juma              6            2010-10-15        m

**diagnosis**
**PID**      **date_done**       **diagnosis_code**
  1           2013-03-20           084
  1           2013-03-13           019
  2           2013-03-17           084
  5           2013-03-13           037
  3           2013-03-21           019
  4           2013-03-01           037
```

I want to get the amount of diagnosis done for <5 >5 and amount of diagnosis for male and female for the month of March

```
                      Year         Gender     
**Diagnosis_code      <5   >5       male    female**
?                    ?     ?         ?        ?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can group by case so this should work.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN d.diagnosis_code <5 THEN '<5' ELSE '>5' END,
       c.sex,
       count(*)
FROM customers c
JOIN diagnosis d
  ON c.pid=d.pid
WHERE d.diagnosis_code<>5
  AND MONTH(d.date_done)=3
GROUP BY CASE WHEN d.diagnosis_code <5 THEN '<5' ELSE '>5' END,
         c.sex;
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/554cf/1) (note that two rows are added to the diagnosis table).

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what `<5` or `>5` means but I am assuming that you mean age.  If that is the case, then you can use:

```
select diagnosis_code,
  sum(case when ageInYears <5 then 1 else 0 end) `<5`,
  sum(case when ageInYears >5 then 1 else 0 end) `>5`,
  sum(case when sex = 'm' then 1 else 0 end) male,
  sum(case when sex = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) female
from
(
  select d.diagnosis_code,
    FLOOR(DATEDIFF(d.date_done, c.BIRTH_DATE)/365.25) AS ageInYears,
    c.sex
  from diagnosis d
  inner join customers c
    on d.pid = c.pid
) src
group by diagnosis_code
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca09d/9)